# How to preserve the language tag in group_concat in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am trying to find the labels for each uri in as many languages as possible. As an example I run this

```
select ?film group_concat (?filmLabel;separator="|") where{
  ?film a dbpedia-owl:Film;rdfs:label ?filmLabel  . FILTER (regex(?film,'Titanic'))
}
```

The result looks like this
[image: Titanic]

I get the labels in different languages but group_concat strips the language tag so I won't know what label belongs to what language. I can use OPTIONAL for each language but it is going to be very messy. What should I do to have the results being aggregated into this format "Titanic_(1953_film)"@en|"Der Untergang der Titanic"@de|"Titanic (película de 1953)"@es so when I post process them I can obtain their corresponding language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of just group_concat'ing the film label, you can group_concat an expression built each row.  In particular, if group_concat on `concat('"',?filmLabel,'"@',lang(?filmLabel)`, you'll get results like what you wanted:

```
select ?film
       (group_concat( concat('"',?filmLabel,'"@',lang(?filmLabel)); separator="|" ) as ?label)
where {
  ?film a dbpedia-owl:Film ;
        rdfs:label ?filmLabel .
  FILTER (regex(?film,'Titanic'))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Ffilm%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28group_concat%28%20concat%28%27%22%27%2C%3FfilmLabel%2C%27%22%40%27%2Clang%28%3FfilmLabel%29%29%3B%20separator%3D%22%7C%22%20%29%20as%20%3Flabel%29%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Ffilm%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3AFilm%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FfilmLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28regex%28%3Ffilm%2C%27Titanic%27%29%29%0D%0A%7D%20&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
film:  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Titanic_(1953_film)
label: "泰坦尼克号 (1953年电影)"@zh|"Titanic (1953 film)"@en|"Der Untergang der Titanic"@de|"Titanic (película de 1953)"@es|"Titanic (film, 1953)"@fr|"Titanic (film 1953)"@it|"タイタニックの最期"@ja|"Titanic (1953)"@nl|"Titanic (film 1953)"@pl|"Titanic (1953)"@pt|"Титаник (фильм, 1953)"@ru

film:  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Titanic:_Blood_and_Steel
label: "Titanic – Blood and Steel"@de|"Titanic: Blood and Steel"@en|"Titanic: sangre y acero"@es|"Titanic : de sang et d'acier (série télévisée, 2012)"@fr|"Titanic - Nascita di una leggenda"@it|"Титаник: Кровь и сталь"@ru
```